# Can Serilog ForContext cause memory leak?

Tags: logging, memory-leaks, serilog

I have this configuration in a web service application:

When the application starts, a root logger is created. This logger is registered as a singleton and used throughout the application:

```
ILogger _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
              .Enrich.FromLogContext()
              .Filter.ByExcluding(e => (int)e.Level < (int)minimumLogLevel)
              .WriteTo
              .ApplicationInsights(TelemetryConfiguration.Active, (logEvent, formatter) => new TelemetryBuilder(logEvent, formatter)
              .LogEventToTelemetryConverter())
              .CreateLogger();
```

For every request that is received by the service, a short-lived handler class is instantiated and receives the logger in the ctor by DI:

```
private ILogger _logger;
public RequestHandler(ISessionStorageProvider sessionStorageProvider, ILogger logger)
        {
            _sessionStorageProvider = sessionStorageProvider;
            _logger = logger.ForContext<CreateSessionHandler>();
        }
```

It then instantiates a private instance of ILogger using a ForContext() call on the root logger above.

The question is, once this handler gets garbage collected, will its private instance _logger also be collected? Or does Serilog hold a reference of the logger created with .ForContext() in the root logger, which would prevent the child logger from being collected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, calling `ILogger.ForContext()`is not known to be a memory leak risk - Serilog does not keep any references to the returned logger object.

Comment: thanks Nicholas for your aswer. Indeed looking at your [blog post](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/08/context-and-correlation-structured-logging-concepts-in-net-5/) you also seem to suggest that ForContext is safe to be used per request. Documentation of Serilog indicates that it is enough to call Dispose on the root logger, you don't need to do it on the child loggers. Then I assume the child logger (created with ForContext) uses the sinks, network handles etc. created by the root logger.